# ostringstream::write method modifies input parameter

Tags: c++, binary-data, ostringstream

Consider the following snippet which gets some binary data and writes it to an `ostringstream` object:

```
unsigned char* payload;
unsigned long  size;

GetData(&payload, &size);

std::cout << md5(payload, size) << std::endl;

std::ostringstream stream;
stream.write((const char*)payload, size);

std::cout << md5(payload, size) << std::endl;
```

The problem is that, two printed hash values are different form each other, which means `payload` has been changed. I tried opening `stream` in binary mode by using `std::ostringstream stream(std::ios::out | std::ios::binary)`, it did not make a difference, I didn't expect that it would, anyway.

Another fact is, I get a different checksum from the second print statement every time I re-run the program. First hash is always the same.

Now, how can I write my binary data correctly to ostringstream? Can the problem be the cast to `const char*` (`GetData` method takes an `unsigned char**` as the first parameter)?

UPDATE: In the light of comments, here are some more explanations:

- Comparing the binary diff of the original data and the data written, I saw written data has shifted to the right (24 bytes) in some places. It has also some added bytes in the very beggining. I'm still thinking it has something to do with the cast.
- There is no more code between `GetData` and the actual writing.
- GetData works correctly, since the checksum after calling it is correct (I know what the checksum should be).
- I cannot post compilable code, because of `GetData`. And it is not necessary, I have isolated the problem to the line where `write` is called.
- System details are: gcc version 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Comment: The interesting code here would be `md5` and its `operator<<`.

Comment: md5 is from haslib++. It is given here just to prove payload is modified, that's how I found out `write` method is the problem.

Comment: @incrediblehulk Hashing algorithms are usually implemented as incremental - when called a second time, they append their argument to their internal buffer from previous calls, unless some sort of restart() is requested in between. Could this be happening here?

Comment: No, I suspected the same and checked it by running multiple md5s before writing. It does not modify the payload for sure.

Comment: So what is the return type of `md5`, and how is the `<<` for it implemented?

Comment: I looked at the source as well, I can 100% assure you md5 is irrelevant to this problem. It copies the payload to an internal buffer first. And I did other integrity checks. I repeat, md5 is given here just for demonstration purposes. The problem is at the line where `write` is called. Believe me :)

Comment: If you've ruled out `md5`, might the problem lie with `GetData`?

Comment: Is there any other code between the two output statements that you haven't posted? I'm having a hard time believing that any implementation of ostringstream::write that modified the data it's supposed to be writing would last long out in the wild.

Comment: The only explanation for this is that your code contains undefined behaviour somewhere or that your compiler or standard library is buggy. Please post a *complete*, *compilable* example that demonstrates your problem (so we can rule out the first possibility), and name your compiler and standard library (so we can investigate the second possibility).

Comment: I made some additions, check the question. First bullet in the update might be interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mystery of the problem turns out to be the size of the data.

After experimenting with different size values, it was discovered that `ostringstream`'s internal buffer is around 65KB, 65504 bytes to be exact. When the size is bigger, strange shifts and crippled bytes occur.

The workaround is to use:

```
stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf((const char*)payload, payloadSize)
```

instead of `write` method. But when this scope terminates, payload will be invalidated and `stream` cannot be used anywhere else anymore. In my case, it needed to be used somewhere else.

This showed that:

- I was indeed right that the issue is with `ostringstream` but not with the hash or anything else.
- String streams of STL apparently have a default buffer size limit. This is to be remembered in the future.